# RxJava 2, Retrofit 2 + Retrolambda - chaining 2 requests together

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android, rx-java2

The first API call returns a list of elements and I then want to subsequently call another API with a `String` returned in each element of the list from the first API call. I (think I) have got it so that it's calling the second API call with each element of the list but I am unsure how to then subscribe to that to get the results returned from the second call.

```
discogsService.getSearchResults(searchTerm, mContext.getString(R.string.token))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                // Turns the result into individual elements
                .flatMapIterable(RootSearchResponse::getSearchResults)
                // I believe this then calls .getRelease() with each ID string
                .map(result -> discogsService.getRelease(result.getId()));
```

**Retrofit Interface:**

```
public interface DiscogsService
{
    @GET("database/search?")
    Observable<RootSearchResponse> getSearchResults(@Query("q") String searchTerm, @Query("token") String token);

    @GET("releases/")
    Observable<Release> getRelease(@Query("release_id") String releaseId);
}
```

I'm unsure where to go from here.

I believe `.subscribe(...)` then gives me the ability to get the `Observable<Release>` returned from each `.getRelease(...)`. As the above method is called in the Model layer I then need to set up a subscriber in this model layer to pass back to the `Presenter` and then an additional subscriber in the `Presenter` to deal with each `Observable` as the `Presenter` has access to the `View`.

Is there a way so that I can just return each Observable from the Model layer so I don't need to have two separate `.subscribe(...)`s? Or should I use two separate `.subscribe(...)`s as I can then catch errors on the both of them? I only want the results from the second call.

Here is the full code that I have tried:

**In Model:**

```
discogsService.getSearchResults(searchTerm, mContext.getString(R.string.token))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMapIterable(RootSearchResponse::getSearchResults)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(result -> discogsService.getRelease(result.getId()))
                .subscribe(new Observer<Observable<Release>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Observable<Release> value)
                    {
                        mainPresenter.addToRecyclerView(value);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete()
                    {

                    }
                });
```

**In Presenter:**

```
@Override
public void addToRecyclerView(Observable<Release> value)
{
    value       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Release>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d)
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Release value)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Success! " + value);
                        results.add(value);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.toString());
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete()
                    {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: I've read your question 5 times, and wasn't able to understand it. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Please show how you used `subscribe` because that is what you need to do. Describe "undesired results" with an example, at least

Comment: do you want to subscribe to both webservice calls and get the result of both of them then do something with the result ?

Comment: Sorry guys, first attempt at RxJava - have updated the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather expose an `Observable<Release>` at model level:

```
Observable<Release> getReleases(...) {
    return discogsService.getSearchResults(...)
        .flatMapIterable(RootSearchResponse::getSearchResults)
        .flatMap(result -> discogsService.getRelease(result.getId()));
}
```

Presenter would just subscribe to it:

```
getReleases
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new Observer<Release>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Release value)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Success! " + value);
            results.add(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete()
        {

        }
    });
```

Only one Observable. Note the switch from `map()` to `flatMap()` for the second request in `getReleases(...)`. Behind the scene this is where occur the second subscribe.

The final subscribe will receive errors from both requests. I prefer to let the consumer (Presenter) handle errors, because it's the one who care about the response and know what to do in case of errors (displaying a message for example).

It's the one who 'drive' the Observable, who create, dispose it, so it's also his duty to assign thread imho.

Observable make very good contract to expose from one layer to another. It describe the data type, how to consume it and the pattern (Observable ? Single ? Flowable ?).